# Should I add tracking in the beginning or end of a function

Tags: swift, analytics

Let's say we have custom analytics library to track screen views and users actions. Considering following options.

```
// Option A
func buyButtonTap() {   
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
    Analytics.track(event: .buy)
}

// Option B
func buyButtonTap() {   
    Analytics.track(event: .buy)
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

Which option would you prefer? Does it matter at all? We have to consider following:

1) Our app and analytics library both use real-time networking and data streaming.
2) "Do something" procedures can be complex and expensive.

Personally, I think that tracking should happen in the end of procedure. And the reason is, that adding tracking in the beginning can add a bit of lag to the app when resources are scarce.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking is not about the main thread, it's a fire-forget task. I think you should call the tracking function in the background thread and don't worry about main thread lag.

```
func buyButtonTap() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        Analytics.track(event: .buy)
    }
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: That’s a good point. So if that’s taken care of, where would you put it? Or does it matter at all? Another reason to do it at last, fellow workers reading this code, they would be more interested in what function does. And another, tracking is optional, and we usually write optional code (like properties) in the end.

Comment: If you don't have to wait for doSomething() or doSomethingElse(), I mean if buy action is actually completed regardless of doSomething() or doSomethingElse() process, call it at start. It actually doesn't important at all, because you're creating a background task on another thread which doesn't affect uithread.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends for example.

if butbuttonTap() is a operation which process the tap operation then you should use option A

```
// Option A
func buyButtonTap() {   
    doSomething()
    doSomethingElse()
    Analytics.track(event: .buy)
}
```

but if butbuttonTap() includes placing order buying items then you should include before the operation as it can crash without finishing doSomething() and         doSomethingElse(). then use

```
// Option B
    func buyButtonTap() {   
        Analytics.track(event: .buy)
        doSomething()
        doSomethingElse()
    }
```

Ideal case is to fragment your method into small parts and make your structure like option A i.e. calling analytics at the end.
as analytics generally used as **didBuy or didTapBuy.**